# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized help databases

Tags: sql, database, dataset, dataadapter, isam

I have been trying to work this out for the last 4 weeks and cannot find the answer I've just been going around in circles. I have had multiple errors with con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection and connection string and ISAM's

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Public sql As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dbPassword As String


        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        dbSource = "C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\Edward\DataBase Login Window\Users.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database"

        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        con.Open()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE accUsername='" & TextBox1.Text & "'AND accPass='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

        da.Fill(ds, "users")

        If ds.Tables("users").Rows.Count = 1 Then
            Dim isAdmin As Boolean = ds.Tables("users").Rows(0).Item(4)
            If isAdmin = True Then
                MsgBox("Logged in.")
                Form4.Show()
                Form4.Username = TextBox1.Text
                Form4.Password = TextBox2.Text
            ElseIf isAdmin = False Then
                MsgBox("Logged in user.")
                Form6.Show()
                Form6.Username = TextBox1.Text
                Form6.Password = TextBox2.Text
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect Username or Password")
        End If

        Me.Hide()

        ds.Clear()
        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub createanaccount_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles createanaccount.Click
        Form2.ShowDialog()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

in the button you should set the connectionString here is an example.

```
dim con as new SQLConnection/OLEDBConnection
con.ConnectionString="Provide your connection string"
con.open
```

I hope this will definitely solve your problem